# /etc under svn - remote repository

Tags: svn

I would like to to put the /etc directory of one client ("client") under svn but with a repository on another machine ("server"). The problem I am facing is with sudo privileges on both machines.

Due to some files/directories under /etc being owned by root, I have to run svn on the "client" with sudo. When I want to commit the files then to the repository on the "server", my problem arises from having to initiate sudo on the "server" as well.

I had hoped something like
`foo = ssh -i /dir/to/sshkey -vttt user@server "sudo svn"` under .subversion/config would do the trick but no.
The error I receive is

> svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://user@server /dir/to/Repo'

Can anyone share a working setup and/or give some pointers?

Comment: https://etckeeper.branchable.com/ but no idea if it's still maintained or how well it worked. See also perhaps https://www.wired.com/2008/04/version-control-begins-at-home/

Comment: etckeeper in combination with git sounds like a better solution: https://www.tecmint.com/manage-etc-with-version-control-using-etckeeper/